# spark-hbase connector expired ticket kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming, cloudera

I have a cluster with CDH 5.8.4. I'm runnin a spark streaming application which reads and writes data from/to HBase by using the cloudera spark-hbase connector namely the HBaseContext.
When I start the application I give the principal and the kinit to the spark-submit script.
I'm seeing that after 7 days the application crashed with an error about the expiration of the ticket kerberos related to the HBase context. This is the error from the executors log:

```
ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 544265.0 (TID 1149098)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java
:326)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.&lt;init&gt;(ClientScanner.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:867)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.restart(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.initialize(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReader.initialize(TableRecordReader.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase$1.initialize(TableInputFormatBase.java:211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.&lt;init&gt;(NewHadoopRDD.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.NewHBaseRDD.compute(NewHBaseRDD.scala:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.NewHBaseRDD.compute(NewHBaseRDD.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Token has expired
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor58.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRowOrBefore(ProtobufUtil.java:1593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1398)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:315)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): Token has expired
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.readStatus(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$700(RpcClientImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.get(ClientProtos.java:34070)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRowOrBefore(ProtobufUtil.java:1589)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance,
Beniamino

Comment: Did you use `--principal` and `--keytab` options when running `spark-submit`?

Comment: Yes I did. The error appears every 7 days when the ticket in the executor cache expires

Comment: Please format your dump to make it `somewhat readable`. And search SO for the answer by Chris Nauroth (HortonWorks, HBase committer) on a similar topic.

Comment: Also, check that your version of Java is supported by CDH. Bad things have happened in the past whenever the core JAAS libs change and Hadoop Auth is not in sync.

Answer (score 2):

We (Splice Machine) had the same issue with a customer.  Our issue was caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12646.  We wrote some code to fix the _HOST issue and we also upgraded to Spark 2.2 to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on an external ticket cache for distributed jobs. The best solution is to ship a keytab with your application or rely on a keytab being deployed on all nodes where your Spark task may be executed.

```
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("name@xyz.com", keyTab);
connection=ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
```

With your approach above, you would need to do something like the following after obtaining the UserGroupInformation instance:

```
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
  public Void run() {
    connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
    ...
    return null;
  }
});
```